# If $\phi(x, y)$ then $x\in A$, for some set $A$ and formula $\phi(x, y)$, is the class $\{x: \phi(x, y)\}$ a set?

Tags: set-theory

The proof of the following theory:

> if $\phi(x)$ then $x\in A$ then the class $\{x: \phi(x)\}$ is a set;

can be obtained by constructing a set:

$
D=\{x\in A: \phi(x)\}
$

and applying the Subset Theory.

However, if $\phi(x)$ is replaced by $\phi(x, y)$ will the conclusion still correct, i.e:

> If $\phi(x, y)$ then $x\in A$ then the class $\{x: \phi(x, y)\}$ is a set;

still correct?

Comment: What would $\{ x : \phi(x, y) \}$ mean? That is, how is $y$ quantified? Do you mean "all those $x$ such that there exists $y$ with $\phi(x, y)$" or "all those $x$ such that for all $y$ we have $\phi(x, y)$"? That is, do you mean $\{x : \exists y \phi(x, y) \}$ or $\{x : \forall y \phi(x, y)\}$? A similar question goes for the bit "If $\phi(x, y)$ then $x \in A$". Note that once this is made precise in one of the above manners you are back in the first scenario from your question (i.e. with one free variable).

Comment: I was initially intended to mean arbitrary $y$, i.e the latter case in your comment. However, for the other case, your comment also gives me a heavy hint of the answer.

Comment: Yes, most formulations of the Subset Axiom allows for finitely many parameters alongside the free variable you are primarily considering ( The justification given by @MarkKamsma hopefully shows why that is valid) The only restriction is that you cannot have D = y, D cannot be a free variable in φ(x,y)  as then you risk creating a self-referential pathological mess. For example imagine φ(x,y) is the formula x∉y, if y = D then D = {x∈A | x∉D}, So y cannot be arbitrary

Comment: @MichaelCarey, "So y cannot be arbitrary" <- For this one, I think you intended to mean: "$y$ can be arbitrary but $D$ is chosen so that it does not appear in $\varphi(x, y)$" ?

Comment: @TranKhanh  sorry for any confusion. Yes, of course. The subset Axiom Scheme works for any formula with arbitrary free variables, ( finitely many) and then we restrict D ( or whatever subset we are trying to show exists) to not being one of those free variables. I.E. As long as the subset D does not appear in φ, D exists by the Axiom